# How to set longvarbinary values in jdbc?

Tags: jdbc, hsqldb

I read that inorder to populate binary values for Insert query you need to create a PreparedStatement and then use setBytes() API to set the byte array as the binary parameter.

My problem is that when i do the same I get "data exception: String data,right truncation".

I read about this that this might come if we populate a value of size more than the declared size. But here I am using a very small byte [] ("s".getbytes()).

I also tried setBinaryStream() but with the same result!

I also tried setting null value. Still I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The length of the VARBINARY or LONGVARBINARY column must be enough to accept the data you are inserting. Your CREATE TABLE statement can contain VARBINARY as the type of the column, allowing up to 16MB per each data item.

If you use BINARY as the type, it means only one byte is allowed.